# Javascript Loose Augmentation and Global import

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to combine loose augmentation with global import and i cant make it work, i understand (i think) how loose augmentation and global import work but how can i make them both in one?
What i wanna do more exactly is that i want to have jquery available inside the anonymous function.

```
var zet = (function (z, $) {
    z.test = function(){
        console.log("test");
    }
    z.jqtest = function(classs){
        $("."+classs).css('backgaround','red');
    }
    return z;
}(zet || {}, jQuery));
zet.test(); 
zet.jqtest("a"); // this is the part at the bottom of the dom after it loaded, but not taking     effect and no error is shown, and yes i do have jquery loaded at the top of the dom
```

help?

Comment: You have a typo in `'backgaround'`. The code itself looks fine.

Comment: This actually works, you just made a typo.

Comment: omg, i just wasted so much time on this just because of that type, just wow, thank you guys